# Adding an on event to an e.currentTarget?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A variety of elements on my page have the content editable tag.

When they are clicked I do this:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('click', this.edit);

p.edit = function(e) {

   console.log(e.currentTarget);
   e.currentTarget.on('keydown', function() {
        alert("keydown...");
   });


};
```

I get the current target ok, but when I try to add keydown to it, I get the err:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Um, are you going to make sure multiple events are not attached?

Answer (score 2):

It's a native DOM element, you'll have to wrap it in jQuery

```
$(e.currentTarget).on('keydown', function() {
    alert("keydown...");
});
```

`e.currentTarget` should equal `this` inside the event handler, which is more commonly used ?

It's a little hard to tell how this works, but I think I would do something like

```
$('[contenteditable]').on({
    click : function() {
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    },
    keydown: function() {
        if ($(this).data('clicked')) 
            alert("keydown...");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2hTjn/)

Comment: Thanks, but the alert is not firing for me.

Comment: Does `p` equal `this`, it does look strange? Open the console and check for errors

Answer (score 1):

First issue is you are trying to use jQuery methods on a DOM element. Second issue is I do not think you want to bind what is clicked on, but the content editable element itself.

It also seems weird to be adding the event on click instead of a global listener. But this is the basic idea

```
$(this)  //current content editable element
    .off("keydown.cust")  //remove any events that may have been added before
    .on('keydown.cust', function(e) {  //add new event listener [namespaced]
        console.log("keydown");  //log it was pressed
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** I had a fail in code. It works fine now.

Getting your code, I improved to this one:

```
$(function(){
    $('[contenteditable]').on('click', function(){
        p.edit($(this));
    });
});

var p = {
    edit: function($e) {
        console.log($e);
        $e.on('keydown', function() {
            console.log($(this));
            alert("keydown...");
        });
     }
}
```

You can **[check it at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/22Apk/1/)**

Comment: `$(this)` is not what you think it is... You just added a keydown event to the document.

Comment: lol you are right, thx for notice me @epascarello, post updated doing it well :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the e.currentTarget(which is a native DOM element) in jQuery since "on" event is a jQuery event:

```
$(e.currentTarget).on('keydown', function() {
    alert("keydown...");
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('click', p.edit);

p.edit = function(e) {

   $(e.currentTarget).on('keydown', function() {
       alert("keydown...");
   });
};
```

You're defining `p.edit` AFTER `$('[contenteditable]').on('click', p.edit);` resulting in an error since `p.edit` doesn't exist when declaring the `on`.

In case you don't know, you are defining `p.edit` as a function expression, meaning that you have to define it BEFORE calling it.